# Yii2: Setting rules for csv file upload and retaining original filename

Tags: php, excel, csv, yii

I'm using yii\web\UploadedFile to upload excel and csv files following the documentation. Uploading works perfectly fine however, I've encountered a couple of weird issues which I can't figure out how to fix.

1. I have expressly stated on my rules to allow xls, xlsx and csv.
   ---> xls and xlsx are uploaded without any problems but csv files throw "Only files with these extensions are allowed: xlsx, xls and csv." error. I am 100% sure that I am uploading a csv file.
   Is there any specific reason this happens? How can it be fixed?
   For now, I've made a workaround by removing extensions on my rules and displaying a  with error message when extension not xls, xlsx or csv but I'd much prefer it if I can use the default from the rules.
2. I mainly use files with japanese filenames. i.e.: テスト０００１.xlsx and テスト０００１.csv. When I try to echo or dump the filename generated on yii, I get the correct filename but when I check uploads folder, the filename changes to something like: 陬ｽ蜩√.xlsx.
   So far, I have tried using iconv to set charset to UTF8 with no luck. I've also tried hardcoding the filename just to check if it has something to do with the actual file but still same results. How can I retain the original filename when uploading the file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ad. 1. This is because there is `checkExtensionByMimeType` option in the `FileValidator`. It is set to `true` by default and it verifies if file extension matches the file MIME type. In case of `csv` files the MIME is usually `text/plain` which causes the validation error.

The solution is to set `checkExtensionByMimeType` to `false` for this kind of file uploads.

See the [discussion about this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6148).

Ad. 2. What version of Yii are you using? In Yii 2.0.10 the [issue with wrong UTF-8 names encoding](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10563) for file downloads has been fixed.

If this is not the case of old version or this issue has no effect on file names being saved maybe this is the problem with your version of ICU.
Check your ICU version by running the `requirements.php` from the main Yii 2 project folder and look for the ICU section.

Comment: Thanks. Regarding the 2nd issue, my Yii version is Yii 2.0.10 while my ICU version is 57.1 so I don't think this is the problem. Do you have any suggestions about other possible causes of this issue?

Comment: Based on the comments regarding similar issues all over the web it looks like this is the internal PHP problem with character encoding. Are you running this in PHP 7? If not, it's worth to try, maybe it's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks for the additional idea and I'm already using PHP 7. After further tweaking, it seems I've manage to resolve the 2nd issue using this piece of code: iconv('UTF-8', 'CP932', $filename)

Comment: i used to follow it beofre but all of a sudden it started giving the same error although i have the correct settings defined in the modal for the file validator and if i rule out the `mimeType` and then try to upload it works, i had `mimeType=>'text/plain'` for the csv file types, also it works correctly for other files but not for one of the files, so its still untraced what is causing the issue. I manually copied all the test to a new `.txt` file and then converted it to a `.csv` but still no change.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent some time with similar issue, only the mimeType for xlsx is not validated on the backend even when setting: `'mimeTypes'=>'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'`
I had to add a double check only for xlsx file type as follows:

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file'], 'file', //'extensions' => 'xlsx,xls',
                'mimeTypes'  => [
                    'application/vnd.ms-excel',
                    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                    ],
                'wrongMimeType'=> \Yii::t('app','Only excel files are allowed.'),
                'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false,
                'skipOnEmpty' => false],
        ];
    }

    public function upload() {
         if ($this->file && ($this->validate() || $this->file->type=='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')) {
            $this->file->saveAs('uploads/' . $this->file->baseName . '.' .
               $this->file->extension);
            return true;
         } else {
            return false;
         }
      }
```

The full example found here: https://yii2-framework.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/input-file-upload/

Hope this helps.